# what this line of code mean....new URLClassLoader(new URL[0],getClass().getClassLoader());

Tags: java

Does above code checks to see if we ( seem to ) have enough permissions to run this code.
I want to know what is purpose of new URLClassLoader(new URL[0],getClass().getClassLoader()); what happens if this code throw exception, and how to grant permission if it throws Securityexception

// quick check to see if we (seem to) have enough permissions to run.

```
        try {
            JVM jvm = new JVM();
            new URLClassLoader(new URL[0],getClass().getClassLoader());
            } catch(SecurityException e) {
            throw new InsufficientPermissionDetected(e);
        }
    }catch (BootFailure e) {
        e.publish(context, home);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. This code runs in a JVM (if it runs) so what is there left to check?

Comment: @Henry I want to know what is purpose of new URLClassLoader(new URL[0],getClass().getClassLoader());   what happens if this code throw exception, and how to grant permission if it throws  Securityexception

Comment: @varun - The question should explain itself.  Use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57534503/edit) to update your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know what is purpose of new URLClassLoader(new URL[0],getClass().getClassLoader());

It means: make a new `URLClassloader` that loads classes / resources from an empty array of URLs, and has this classes classloader as the parent.

The resulting classloader object is then discarded.

So I think this is just testing to see if the application is permitted to create a classloader.

The class `JVM` is not one that I recognize.  I don't know what that is about.

> what happens if this code throw exception

Nothing happens apart from the obvious.  If the exception is a `SecurityException` you wrap it and throw it as a different exception.  Otherwise the exception propagates.

The `InsufficientPermissionDetected` class may be a Hudson or Jenkins class.  If that is the case, examine the rest of the Hudson or Jenkins codebase to see how it handles the exception.

> [how do I] grant permission if it throws `SecurityException`

It depends on what platform the code is executed on.

- If you are running on non-sandboxed Java JVM, you should already have permission ... to do everything.
- If you are running on a sandboxed Java JVM, then the permission must be granted by the sandboxing mechanism.   For example, with a trusted JAR file:

  - The JAR must be signed with a CERT that the user / user's JVM trusts.
  - The code in the JAR file is then permitted to access controlled APIs as per the policy file that is in force.

  For more details, start by reading ["Trail: Security Features in Java SE"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/)
- If you are running on Android .... not sure.

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation

Comment: Its a pity that you didn't fix the question.  Because you didn't bother, it got lots of downvotes, and will probably end up being deleted.